# How can I create these two pictures in LaTeX, using tikz or circuitikz?

Tags: circuitikz

[image]

The image depicts an optomechanical system, where a coplanar waveguide interacts with a nanomechanical oscillating capacitor mediated by a qubit.

I want to create images (a) and (b) both in `LaTeX`. I have tried to make the nanomechanical oscillating capacitor in `circuiTikZ` but couldn't, while other parts were easy. Image (a), on the other hand, I could not replicate perfectly.

Added by @Rmano: so you can see how to properly prepare a question

Code:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
    \ctikzset{bipoles/thickness=3, resistors/thickness=4, capacitors/thickness=4,
    inductors/thickness=4, batteries/thickness=4}
    \begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.77,transform shape]
         \draw  (0,0)to[inductor](0,4) (3,0)to[capacitor](3,4)
            (0,0)--(3,0)  (0,4)--(3,4); %
         \draw[red] (3,4)to[capacitor](7,4)--(7,3); %
         \draw (5,3)--(7,3)--(9,3); %
         \draw[blue] (5,3)to[barrier](5,1)
            (6,3)to[barrier](6,1)
            (9,3)to[capacitor,l=$C_j$](9,1)
            (5,1)--(9,1)
            (7,1)--(7,0)node[ground]{}; %
         \draw (7,4)--(10.5,4); %
         \draw (10.5,4)to[capacitor,l=$C_{NMR}$]
            (10.5,1.5)to[battery](10.5,0)node[ground]{};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

The thing I would like to correct is the NAMR capacitor and the battery.

Comment: Welcome to TeX,SE! What you try' Where you stuck? This site is not service "we-will-do-instead-you" ...

Comment: You say that you tried at least something. Please provide the code you got so far. This will make it much easier to help you.

Comment: The main problem in circuitikz is that bi-color capacitors are not there (although you can try some trick). Show what you have tried and we'll try to help.

Comment: I have copied and formatted your code for you in the question. Now, use the [edit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/682577/edit) link to complete it; fill in *what exactly* you want to fix in your code. BTW, welcome!

Comment: Thankyou @Rmano for help with the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no symbol similar to the NMR capacitor you want, so the solution is to build it with basic Ti*k*Z commands.

I would use a different way of describing the circuit, but in this case, I just changed the part I marked with the comment below.

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
    \ctikzset{bipoles/thickness=3, resistors/thickness=4, capacitors/thickness=4,
    inductors/thickness=4, batteries/thickness=4}
    \begin{circuitikz}[american, cute inductors, scale=0.77,transform shape]
         \draw  (0,0)to[inductor](0,4) (3,0)to[capacitor](3,4)
            (0,0)--(3,0)  (0,4)--(3,4); %
         \draw[red] (3,4)to[capacitor](7,4)--(7,3); %
         \draw (5,3)--(7,3)--(9,3); %
         \draw[blue] (5,3)to[barrier](5,1)
            (6,3)to[barrier](6,1)
            (9,3)to[capacitor,l=$C_j$](9,1)
            (5,1)--(9,1)
        %%% start editing from here
            (7,1)--(7,0)node[ground](GND){}; %get the position of ground
         \draw (7,4)--(10.5,4) coordinate(cnmr left); %
         \draw[ultra thick] (cnmr left) ++(0,-0.5)  -- ++(0,1);
         \draw (cnmr left) ++(0.4,0) node[right]{$C_{\mathit{NMR}}$} 
            ++(0,-0.5) node[squarepole](cnmr low){}
            to[bend left] ++(0,1) node[squarepole]{};
            \draw (cnmr low) to[V=$V_{\mathit{NR}}$, invert]
                % use perpendicular coordinate to position ground
                (cnmr low |- GND)node[ground]{};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

which gives you

[image]

Notice that the symbol for `V` changes if you remove the `american` from the option; I also added `cute inductors` to maintain the shape of the inductor. (PS: you should also add the ground connection to the left-hand LC tank...)